# Deep Linking with Authentication going to different screens

Tags: react-native, authentication, expo, deep-linking

I'm building a mobile blockchain application with React Native and React Navigation that requires authentication on most deep links. I'm new to deep links, and am having trouble understanding how to get to the correct screen using deep links. As an example below:

One of my links has the format `myapp://addConnection/:username/:address/:screenToNavigateTo?`
(`username` is a username for another user and `address` is a blockchain address for another user.)

The way I understand how all deep links that require authentication work, is that the link will point to a page in the signedOut stack (in my case `Login.js`), authenticate the user, and then navigate to the correct screen with the proper parameters. However, what I don't understand is how to access parameters across multiple deep links. Right now, my`Login.js` component looks like this:

```
import ...

export default function LoginPopUp({ route, navigation }) {

  const { key, newWallet, username, address, nextscreen } = route.params; // I want to figure out how to make the last 3 parameters into a single object, or figure out a way to get to the correct screen without having to do this in such an hacky way. 
  const { user, setUser } = useContext(UserContext);
  const { wallet, setWallet } = useContext(WalletContext);
  const { auth, setAuth } = useContext(AuthContext);
useEffect(() => {
    async function shouldNav() {
      if (nextscreen !== undefined) {
        setAuth((p) => ({ ...p, details: {username: username, address: address, nextScreen: nextscreen }));
      } 
       // How can I make this so any deep link will work here, not just the one above?
    }
    shouldNav();
  }, []);
  async function registerWallet() {
    //registers a blockchain wallet with the user account
  }
  async function handleLogin() {
    //handles user login
  }
  
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {/*Login component*/}
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({...})
```

My `App.js` component looks like this:

```
import ...

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();
const SignedInStack = createNativeStackNavigator();
const SignedOutStack = createNativeStackNavigator();


const prefix = Linking.createURL("/");

function SignedInScreens() {
  return (
    <SignedInStack.Navigator>
       ... //Home, AddUser, and more
    </SignedInStack.Navigator/>
  );
}
function SignedOutScreens() {
  return (
    <SignedOutStack.Navigator>
       ... //Welcome, Register, Login
    </SignedOutStack.Navigator/>
  );
}
export default function App({ navigation, route }) {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  const [wallet, setWallet] = useState(null);
  const [auth, setAuth] = useState(null);
  const w = { wallet, setWallet };
  const u = { user, setUser };
  const a = { auth, setAuth };
  const [signedIn, setSignedIn] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    async function set() {
      //sets signedIn
    }
    set();
  }, [auth]);
  useEffect(() => {
    async function set() {
        //checks if wallet is present, if so sets
    }
    set();
  }, [auth]);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function set() {
        //checks if user is present, if so sets
    }
    set();
  }, [auth]);
  const linking = {
    prefixes: ["blkcnnct://"],
    config: {
      screens: {
        Login: {
          path: "adduser/:address/:name/:nextscreen?",
          parse: {
            nextscreen: (nextscreen) => `${nextscreen}`,
            address: (address) => `${address}`,
            username: (username) => `${username}`,
          },
          // I will want to add more deep links eventually
        },
      },
    },
  };
  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={a}>
      <UserContext.Provider value={u}>
        <WalletContext.Provider value={w}>
          <NavigationContainer
            linking={linking}
            ref={navigationRef}
            fallback={<Text>Loading...</Text>}
          >
            <Stack.Navigator>
              {signedIn ? (
                   <Stack.Screen
                    name="SignedInScreens"
                    component={SignedInScreens}
                    options={{ headerShown: false }}
                  />
              ) : (
                   <Stack.Screen
                    name="SignedOutScreens"
                    component={SignedOutScreens}
                    options={{ headerShown: false }}
                  />
              )}
            </Stack.Navigator>
          </NavigationContainer>
        </WalletContext.Provider>
      </UserContext.Provider>
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

I'm sure what I'm doing is not the optimal way of doing a deep link with authentication, and if I need to provide more information, please let me know. My `App.js` component is fairly simple, the authentication flow is controlled by `AuthContext` and `signedIn`, and the deep link does work to get the correct parameters into `Login.js`.  My issue is for multiple deep links, I wouldn't be able to get the deep link parameters to the correct screen, because they need to be parsed individually, which would require way too many parameters in the `route.params` for `Login.js`, and I can't figure out how to group them together so I can pull them from `route.params` in a single object.

If I need to approach this a different way, or if there is just a much more efficient way of doing this, I'd also love an explanation, as I can't find anything online. Thank you!